# Count all products with search function

Tags: php, function

I’ve been trying to call a function and it just doesn’t seem to work.
So, this is `function count_all_products_q`. This is needed for pagination.

```
 function count_all_products_q($options=[]) {
global $db;

$visible = $options['visible'] ?? false;

$search_statement = isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : '';
if ($search_statement == '') {
$search_statement = isset($_GET['search']) ? $_GET['search'] : '';        
}  

$search = h(db_escape($db, $search_statement));

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products ";
if ($search != '') {            
$search = h(db_escape($db, $search_statement));     
$sql .= "WHERE (`prod_name` LIKE '%".$search."%') ";
    }
if($visible) {
  $sql .= "AND visible = true ";
}   
$sql .= "ORDER BY position ASC";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
confirm_result_set($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
mysqli_free_result($result);
//[0] - I want only one number.
$count = $row[0];
return $count;

  }
```

**search.php**

```
$products_count = count_all_products_q(['visible' => $visible]);

    //if count is nothing ('') redirect to....
    if($products_count == '') {
          redirect_to(url_for('/index.php'));
    }
```

This part doesn’t work `if($products_count == '')` when I click search by mistake, instead of redirection, I have `Database query failed` `(search.php?search=)`.

Am I missing something, did I do something wrong? Thanks for your attention!

**UPDATE2** everything works!

search.php

```
$visible = $visible ?? true;

$search_statement = isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : '';
    if ($search_statement == '') {
$search_statement = isset($_GET['search']) ? $_GET['search'] : '';        
    } 

$search = h(db_escape($db, $search_statement));

if($search == '') {
      redirect_to(url_for('/index.php'));
}

$products_count = count_all_products_q(['visible' => $visible]);
```

Comment: Try to debug $count or $row and share your output here

Comment: `echo $products_count; 92` `search.php?search=`

Comment: some searched word "a" `$products_count; 25` `search.php?search=a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem with the code where you are concatenating "WHERE" condition. 
**if($visible) then "WHERE"** which is wrong and will give query error if this condition fails. Also **$options['visible'] ?? false;** this code may cause issue depending on the version on PHP. You can change your conditions like this to make it work in all scenarios.Followed by rest of the logic.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products WHERE 1 ";
if($visible) { 
     $sql .= "AND visible = true "; 
}
if ($search != '') {
     $search = h(db_escape($db, $search_statement));
     $sql .= "AND (prod_name LIKE '%".$search."%') ";
}
```

Comment: Please check UPDATE1. I did it `$sql .= "WHERE is search, AND is  visible `  In function don't work but in search.php works. I don't understand this.

Comment: Try using this in your function .. **Step 1**
`$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products WHERE 1 ";`
Then change this condition 

`if($visible) { 
        $sql .= "AND visible = true "; 
}`

And keep the rest same.

Comment: Your query is saying SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products WHERE **visible = true** ORDER BY position ASC .. Is visible is type Boolean or Varchar ? Probably **true** is considered as string in this case?

Comment: `visible` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL, 1 or 0

Comment: So you query should say `visible = 1` or `visible = 0` - depending on the condition, should work then.

Comment: Now it seems that everything is working, if you want chceck please UPDATE2 and new function.

Answer (score 1):

In case there is no visible is false ans search has text your query will be broken
In this case you should

```
        if($visible) { 
           $sql .= "WHERE visible = true "; 
        }
        if ($search != '') {
           $search = h(db_escape($db, $search_statement));
           $sql .= $visible ? 'AND ' : 'WHERE';
           $sql .= " (`prod_name` LIKE '%".$search."%') ";
        }
```

Not tested but I hope you can see your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did as you wrote, In function don't work but in search.php work. It is strange:)

Answer (score 0):

Print your query with echo $sql or with echo  $this->db->query()
Run directly in mysql and check why it is getting failed.
May you have generate wrong query.

Comment: sql `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products WHERE visible = true ORDER BY position ASC`  `search.php?search=`